# How to force Hibernate Validator to validate fields recursively(cascaded)?

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have the following model:

```
class EmailWrapper {

    @Email
    private String subscriptionEmail;

    private MyClass myClass;
    //get and set
}


class MyClass {
    @Size(min = 12)
    private String str = "short";
    //get and set
}
```

and following code:

```
EmailWrapper emailWrapper = new EmailWrapper();
emailWrapper.setSubscriptionEmail("qq@gmail.com");
emailWrapper.setMyClass(new MyClass());
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<EmailWrapper>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(emailWrapper);
System.out.println(constraintViolations.size());
```

As You can see that `emailWrapper.myClass.str` violates the `@Size(min = 12)`

but I see `0` in console. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
private MyClass myClass;
```

by

```
@Valid
private MyClass myClass;
```

Comment: To give some background, [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-object-graph-validation) in the reference guide discusses cascaded validation. It also works for collections/arrays.